# How to draw polygons on an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I need to know how to draw polygons on a canvas. Without using jQuery or anything like that.

Comment: It's good to remember that whatever can be done without a third-party library, should usually be done so.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Create a path with `moveTo` and `lineTo` ([live demo](https://phihag.de/2018/so/canvas.html)):

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 90);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: @Gio Borje: AFAIK, jsFiddle doesn't care about canvas, that's your browser. jsFiddle just feeds your HTML/CSS/JS back to you.

Comment: Excellent solution. Very neat code. thank u @phihag. Something that I can understand!

Comment: can you replace c2 with ctx? I think it's more common use for canvas context. great answer by the way

Comment: @user1893354 Thank you very much for the notice. Indeed, there seems to be a problem with jsfiddle there - the error message is completely unrelated to the canvas.  Replaced with a very simple live demo site.

Answer (score 49):

from http://www.scienceprimer.com/drawing-regular-polygons-javascript-canvas:

The following code will draw a hexagon. Change the number of sides to create different regular polygons.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('hexagon').getContext('2d');

// hexagon
var numberOfSides = 6,
    size = 20,
    Xcenter = 25,
    Ycenter = 25;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          

for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
  ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}

ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#hexagon { border: thin dashed red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="hexagon"></canvas>
```

Comment: This was great, very elegant, also, if you add: 
`cxt.save();`
`cxt.fillStyle = "#FF000";`
`cxt.fill();`
`cxt.restore();`

You can fill the shape.

Comment: this is great - i've been sitting playing with it, but cannot work out how i would get the chosen polygon to rotate - any ideas?

Comment: There are a few ways to get what you want. One option is to use the built in cxt.rotate() method [along with cxt.save() and cxt.restore()] to rotate parts of the canvas. Alternatively, adding a consistent value to the cos and sin functions will also work. See this jsfiddle for a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/kwyhn3ba/

Comment: thanks for that - i came across the same solution after reading through the logic on the science primer link you provided. `var angle = i * 2 * Math.PI / shape.currentSides + rotation` added to the cos and sin values worked for me... thanks again

Comment: If (as in my case) you just want the starting point to be the middle top of the polygon rather than the middle right, flip the `sin` and `cos` calls and change `Ycenter +` to `Ycenter -` on both places (leaving it as a sum rather than a difference of the values results in it starting with a point at the bottom of the resultant shape).  I am not a clever man when it comes to trig, so take with a grain of salt; but this achieved what I wanted at least.

Answer (score 42):

```
//poly [x,y, x,y, x,y.....];
var poly=[ 5,5, 100,50, 50,100, 10,90 ];
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(poly[0], poly[1]);

for(let item=2 ; item < poly.length-1 ; item+=2 ){
  ctx.lineTo( poly[item] , poly[item+1] )
}
 
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: This is why I wish I could fundamentally understand the JavaScript vanilla `for` method.  That one line of code simplified things so much.  I typically use the jQuery `.each()` but it's application is much less versatile.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon The javascript above is really not a good example. *All* variables need `var`, in the above code `item` is a polluting the global namespace. Everything is on one line, which reduces readability. If you don't care about readability then you might as well remove the curly brackets.

Comment: @canvastag Nice work dynamic job. This answer is better from accepted answer for me. I don't understand "Query .each()" ... this is some magic function who does take memory. Also for global namespace ;) funny this is just example make it like class if you want that.

Answer (score 10):

```
//create and fill polygon
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillPolygon = function (pointsArray, fillColor,     strokeColor) {
    if (pointsArray.length <= 0) return;
    this.moveTo(pointsArray[0][0], pointsArray[0][1]);
    for (var i = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++) {
        this.lineTo(pointsArray[i][0], pointsArray[i][1]);
    }
    if (strokeColor != null && strokeColor != undefined)
        this.strokeStyle = strokeColor;

    if (fillColor != null && fillColor != undefined) {
        this.fillStyle = fillColor;
        this.fill();
    }
}
//And you can use this method as 
var polygonPoints = [[10,100],[20,75],[50,100],[100,100],[10,100]];
context.fillPolygon(polygonPoints, '#F00','#000');
```

Comment: Interesting... Actually does a moveTo AND a lineTo for the first point... but now that I think about it... who cares?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that even supports clockwise/anticlockwise drawing do that you control fills with the non-zero winding rule.

[Here is a full article on how it works and more.](http://www.storminthecastle.com/2013/07/24/how-you-can-draw-regular-polygons-with-the-html5-canvas-api/)

```
// Defines a path for any regular polygon with the specified number of sides and radius, 
// centered on the provide x and y coordinates.
// optional parameters: startAngle and anticlockwise

function polygon(ctx, x, y, radius, sides, startAngle, anticlockwise) {
  if (sides < 3) return;
  var a = (Math.PI * 2)/sides;
  a = anticlockwise?-a:a;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate(startAngle);
  ctx.moveTo(radius,0);
  for (var i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(radius*Math.cos(a*i),radius*Math.sin(a*i));
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();
}

// Example using the function.
// Define a path in the shape of a pentagon and then fill and stroke it.
context.beginPath();
polygon(context,125,125,100,5,-Math.PI/2);
context.fillStyle="rgba(227,11,93,0.75)";
context.fill();
context.stroke();
```

Comment: That article is rather long to say "your drawing a circle with less edges". You might want to cache the results to avoid calling cos and sin so much (forgive me if its doing it already, I'm not a JavaScript programmer).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @canvastag, use a `while` loop with `shift` I think is more concise:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var poly = [5, 5, 100, 50, 50, 100, 10, 90];

// copy array
var shape = poly.slice(0);

ctx.fillStyle = '#f00'
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(shape.shift(), shape.shift());
while(shape.length) {
  ctx.lineTo(shape.shift(), shape.shift());
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lineTo() method same as:
 var objctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

```
        objctx.beginPath();
        objctx.moveTo(75, 50);
        objctx.lineTo(175, 50);
        objctx.lineTo(200, 75);
        objctx.lineTo(175, 100);
        objctx.lineTo(75, 100);
        objctx.lineTo(50, 75);
        objctx.closePath();
        objctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        objctx.fill();
```

if you not want to fill the polygon use the stroke() method in the place of fill()

You can also check the following: http://www.authorcode.com/draw-and-fill-a-polygon-and-triangle-in-html5/

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the people looking for regular polygons:

```
function regPolyPath(r,p,ctx){ //Radius, #points, context
  //Azurethi was here!
  ctx.moveTo(r,0);
  for(i=0; i<p+1; i++){
    ctx.rotate(2*Math.PI/p);
    ctx.lineTo(r,0);
  }
  ctx.rotate(-2*Math.PI/p);
}
```

Use:

```
//Get canvas Context
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.translate(60,60);    //Moves the origin to what is currently 60,60
//ctx.rotate(Rotation);  //Use this if you want the whole polygon rotated
regPolyPath(40,6,ctx);   //Hexagon with radius 40
//ctx.rotate(-Rotation); //remember to 'un-rotate' (or save and restore)
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function approach at three different ways to draw polygons.

1. Origin, size and radius
2. Points in a flat array `[x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xN, yN]`
3. Points in a point array `{ x: int, y: int }[]`

Stroke is the default, but fill can also be called. These could either be moved outside the function, or boolean parameters can be added. Alternatively, there can be two methods `fillPolygon` or `strokePolygon`, but these are now limited in functionality.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('drawing').getContext('2d');

const main = () => {
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  drawPolygon(ctx, 25, 25, 20);      // Triangle (default)
  drawPolygon(ctx, 75, 25, 20, 6);   // Hexagon
  drawPolygon(ctx, 125, 25, 20, 20); // Icosahedron

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#070';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0';
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;

  drawFreePolygon(ctx, [30, 80, 30, 100, 70, 100, 70, 80, 50, 60]);
  ctx.fill();
  drawFreePolygon2(ctx, [{ x: 90, y: 80 }, { x: 90, y: 100 }, { x: 130, y: 100 }, { x: 130, y: 80 }, { x: 110, y: 60 }]);
};

const drawPolygon = (ctx, x, y, radius, sides = 3) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius * Math.cos(0), y + radius * Math.sin(0));
  for (let i = 1; i <= sides; i += 1) {
    ctx.lineTo(x + radius * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides), y + radius * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides));
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke(); // Could be called outside
};

const drawFreePolygon = (ctx, points) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0], points[1]);
  for (let i = 2; i < points.length - 1; i += 2) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke(); // Could be called outside
};

const drawFreePolygon2 = (ctx, points) => {
  const [{ x: startX, y: startY }] = points;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  points.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  });
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke(); // Could be called outside
};

main();
```

```css
#hexagon { border: thin dashed red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="drawing"></canvas>
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694484/1762224

Answer (score 0):

To make a simple hexagon without the need for a loop, Just use the beginPath() function. Make sure your **canvas.getContext('2d')** is the equal to **ctx** if not it will not work.

I also like to add a variable called times that I can use to scale the object if I need to.This what I don't need to change each number.

```
     // Times Variable 

     var times = 1;

    // Create a shape

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(99*times, 0*times);
    ctx.lineTo(99*times, 0*times);
    ctx.lineTo(198*times, 50*times);
    ctx.lineTo(198*times, 148*times);
    ctx.lineTo(99*times, 198*times);
    ctx.lineTo(99*times, 198*times);
    ctx.lineTo(1*times, 148*times);
    ctx.lineTo(1*times,57*times);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do that with HTML and get that down to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title> SVG hexagon </title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <svg width="300" height="110" >
     <polygon point="50 3, 100 28, 100 75, 50 100, 3 75, 3 25" stroke="red" fill="lime" stroke-width="5"/>
   </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('hexagon').getContext('2d');

// hexagon
var numberOfSides = 4,
    size = 25,
    Xcenter = 40,
    Ycenter = 40;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          

for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
  ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}

ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#hexagon { border: thin dashed red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="hexagon"></canvas>
```