# How would you code this calculator?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, calculator

I need to make a web calculator with 5 numer inputs and the result should be as in the attached images. The red & blue area should change its size based on the input values. Ususing a static background wont work, it must scale on certain input values as in the second image.

What would you use? CSS&javascript? I tried to convert the image to a carnvas without luck, I get 4megabytes of code and converting it to svg didn't worked either I only the get the red poligon.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why the -ve votes people ? Its a valid question, its complete and has "What he has tried".

Comment: If you have a -ve vote, please put in a comment too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript to draw this quite easily.  The link below should help you get started.

[How to draw polygons on an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839993/how-to-draw-polygons-on-an-html5-canvas)