# How do I give a CSS octagon shape a full border?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to take this css Octagon and give it a solid red border. However, when i add the border it only works on portion of the shape. Does anyone have a solution for this?

[image]

Here is a [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kfvnbxp0/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='octagonWrap'>
      <div class='octagon'></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.octagonWrap{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        }
    .octagon{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
    .octagon:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        background: #777;
        content: '';
        border: 3px solid red;
        }
```

Comment: Take a hobo to a smorgasbord, and then give him to the CSS Octagon ("border" not "boarder").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify your own code to work with this. Right now, you have rules for `.octagon` that should be for `.octagon-wrapper`, and rules for `.octagon::before` that should be for `.octagon`. Just shift the CSS rules and have them apply to their parents, while changing the `border` property of `.octagon::before` to inherit from `.octagon`.

```css
.octagonWrap {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.octagon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #777;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.octagon:before {
    position: absolute;
    /* There needs to be a negative value here to cancel
     * out the width of the border. It's currently -3px,
     * but if the border were 5px, then it'd be -5px.
     */
    top: -3px; right: -3px; bottom: -3px; left: -3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: '';
    border: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class='octagonWrap'>
    <div class='octagon'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask you an additional question?

Comment: Sure thing. No need to ask permission to ask a question--the back and forth makes that take longer.

Answer (score 9):

## SVG solution

I do not know if using svg is an option,
If it is here is how simple it is done.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 75 75" width="200px">
  <path d="m5,22 18,-18 28,0 18,18 0,28 -18,18, -28,0 -18,-18z" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hello! This works great actually! Do you have a path for an 8pointer star? Also where do you find these "cords" ?

Comment: the "cords" are created by hand by me, if you want to createshapes with curves and what not take a look here: [Path mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that very effectively with `clip-path`

```css
.octagonWrap {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
}

.octagon {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="octagonWrap">
  <div class='octagon'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [online calculator](http://www.had2know.com/academics/octagon-measurement-calculator.html) (or calculate it manually) to compute the size in which the ratio of the side, and overall height needs to be.

Then by using some pseudos and a span element, you could create this shape via:

```css
.oct {
  height: 241px;
  width: 100px;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 10px solid tomato;
  border-bottom: 10px solid tomato;
  margin: 100px auto;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.oct:before,
.oct:after,
.oct span {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  border: inherit;
  top: -10px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.oct:before {
  left: -100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.oct:after {
  left: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.oct span {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.oct:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="oct">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine those red lines extending until they touch each other.  That square (rotated 45%) has a complete border, you just don't see the "cut off" corners due to the overflow: hidden;

This seems to work (but does so by adding two extra divs, so there may be a better way):

```
<div class='octagonWrap'>
  <div class='octagon'></div>
  <div class='vert'> </div>
  <div class='hort'> </div>
</div>
```

and then add tihs css:

```
.vert {
     position: absolute;
     left: 60px;
     border-top: 3px solid red;
     border-bottom: 3px solid red;
     height: 194px;
     width: 80px;
 }
 .hort {
     position: absolute;
     top: 60px;
     border-left: 3px solid red;
     border-right: 3px solid red;
     width: 94px;
     height: 80px;
 }
```

Comment: If I add a border to the wrap it just shows the square around it.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate? Or post your version of JSFiddle?

Comment: it deserve a link or a snippet to the whole thing ;) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMpoEV

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the HTML5 canvas element. You should be able to [draw the polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839993/how-to-draw-polygons-on-an-html5-canvas) and then add a stroke to it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw such a code inside the Metronik theme code, and in my opinion, it was unmatched in terms of beauty, and you can also use it.

```
.octagon {clip-path: polygon(46.1731656763% .7612046749%,47.411809549% .3407417371%,48.6947380778% .0855513863%,50% 0,51.3052619222% .0855513863%,52.588190451% .3407417371%,53.8268343237% .7612046749%,82.1111055711% 12.4769334274%,83.2842712475% 13.0554747147%,84.3718855375% 13.7821953496%,85.3553390593% 14.6446609407%,86.2178046504% 15.6281144625%,86.9445252853% 16.7157287525%,87.5230665726% 17.8888944289%,99.2387953251% 46.1731656763%,99.6592582629% 47.411809549%,99.9144486137% 48.6947380778%,100% 50%,99.9144486137% 51.3052619222%,99.6592582629% 52.588190451%,99.2387953251% 53.8268343237%,87.5230665726% 82.1111055711%,86.9445252853% 83.2842712475%,86.2178046504% 84.3718855375%,85.3553390593% 85.3553390593%,84.3718855375% 86.2178046504%,83.2842712475% 86.9445252853%,82.1111055711% 87.5230665726%,53.8268343237% 99.2387953251% 52.588190451% 99.6592582629%,51.3052619222% 99.9144486137%,50% 100%,48.6947380778% 99.9144486137%,47.411809549% 99.6592582629%,46.1731656763% 99.2387953251%,17.8888944289% 87.5230665726%,16.7157287525% 86.9445252853%,15.6281144625% 86.2178046504%,14.6446609407% 85.3553390593%,13.7821953496% 84.3718855375%,13.0554747147% 83.2842712475%,12.4769334274% 82.1111055711%,.7612046749% 53.8268343237%,.3407417371% 52.588190451%,.0855513863% 51.3052619222%,0 50%,.0855513863% 48.6947380778%,.3407417371% 47.411809549%,.7612046749% 46.1731656763%,12.4769334274% 17.8888944289%,13.0554747147% 16.7157287525%,13.7821953496% 15.6281144625%,14.6446609407% 14.6446609407%,15.6281144625% 13.7821953496%,16.7157287525% 13.0554747147%,17.8888944289% 12.4769334274%);
```

You can also see the code that others are writing and it is working inside this page.
I put the reference [link here](https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo1/landing.html).